# Unable to get pathname from a nested route inside middleware.js in next js 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, app-router

I am following the App Router official documentation at
[Authentication](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization)

I am trying the get the pathname from the next URL

```
export function middleware(request) {
    console.log('new we are in middleware');
    const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
    const pathnameHasLocale = locales.some(
        (locale) => pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || pathname === `/${locale}`
    )


    const locale = locales.find(k => pathname.startsWith(`/${k}/`) || pathname === `/${k}`);


    if(currentRole === ROLES.ADMIN) {
        console.log(pathname);
       
        if(!pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/customer`) ) {
            if(!pathname.startsWith(`/${'en'}`)) {
                request.nextUrl.pathname = `/en`
                return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl);
            }
        }
       

    }
}
```

When I try to visit a path like /en/products

It should return

```
/en/products
```

But it just returns
/en

The directory structure is

```
root
   --app
     --[lang]
         --products
         page.js
         -
         -
   middleware.js
   -
   -
```

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure should like bellow:

```
root
   --app
     --[lang]
       --products
         page.js
         -
         -
   middleware.js
   -
```